# Is it possible to add 1,000,000 doubles in one clock cycle on a GPU?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

I'm curious: on a GPU, is it possible to add millions of numbers in parallel, within a few clock cycles - or is this operation something that is theoretically impossible to parallelize?

By GPU, I mean any offering from nVidia or AMD, e.g. Tesla M2050.

Comment: This is pretty off topic for Stackoverflow, but the answer is no. The NVIDIA GPU you mention has a maximum arithmetic throughput of 1 double precision multiply-add per core per 2 clock cycles, and 448 cores. You do the math.......

Comment: @Mat: Millions _in one clock cycle_ is a very big issue. That is a petaflop/s on a device with a 1GHz clock speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In only one clock cycle, or a "few"?  If the former, then no, there are nowhere near enough hardware resources in any GPU to add millions of doubles in the same clock cycle.  If you mean "relatively few clock cycles with respect to a typical CPU", then yes.  The type of addition you wish to perform also plays a factor.  For example, are you doing a reduction sum on the elements of an array?  Or adding two vectors together?  Or adding a constant to a vector?  These all have different performance characteristics on GPUs.